# XML serialization using XStream

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xstream

I have the following classes:

```
class MMS {
   @XStreamAlias("mouse")
   Mouse mMouse;
   @XStreamAlias("less")
   String  mLess;
   @XStreamAlias("ress")
   int mRess;
}
class Mouse {

   String name;
   int size;
   int rest;    
}
```

after XStream using I have the following:

```
<MMS>
  <mouse>
    <name>Name</name>
    <size>255</size>
    <rest>1</rest>
  </mouse>
  <less>fine</less>
  <ress>1</less>
<MMS>
```

Please help me to resolve the problem. I need to have

```
<MMS>
  <name>
  <size>
  <rest>
  <less>fine</less>
  <ress>1</less>
<MMS>
```

Comment: What language or platform is this? Java?

Comment: Thanks. You'll get better Java answers if you use the [tag:java] tag.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the specified xml if you have your java class as follows :

```
class MMS {
   String name;
   int size;
   int rest;  
   @XStreamAlias("less")
   String  mLess;
   @XStreamAlias("ress")
   int mRess;
}
```

Would you either update the classes or create a new class that extend the properties ?